# Is the proof $diam(A\cup B) \le diam(A) +diam(B)+d(A, B)$ logically perfect?

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

$(X, d) $ be a metric space and $A, B$ be two non empty bounded subsets of $X$.

To show : $$diam(A\cup B) \le diam(A) +diam(B)+d(A, B)$$

Notations:

$diam(A) =Sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\}$

$d(A,B) = Inf\{d(x,y): x\in A, y\in B\}$

My attempt:
$(X, d) $ metric space.$ x, y\in X$

$diam(A\cup B) =sup\{d(x, y) : x, y \in A\cup B\}$

$x, y\in A\cup B $ this implies both $x, y \in A $ or $x, y \in B$ or, one of them belongs to $A$ and other belongs to $B$.

We will consider two cases

Case 1: Both $x, y\in A $ ,(similarly both $x,y \in B$) then

\begin{align} d(x, y)&\le\sup\{d(x, y):x, y \in A\}\\
&=diam(A) \end{align}

$\begin{align} diam(A)&\le diam(A) +diam(B) +d(A, B)\end{align}$

Hence,\begin{align} diam(A) +diam(B) +d(A, B)\end{align}
is an upper bound of $\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\cup B\}.$

And hence, \begin{align} diam (A\cup B) &=sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\cup B\}\\
&\le diam(A) +diam(B) +d(A, B) \end{align}

And similarly, $x, y\in B \implies diam(A\cup B \le diam(B)\le diam(A) +diam(B) +d(A, B) $

Case 2: $x, y$ doesn't belongs to the same set.(A Or B)

W.L.O.G we asumme
$x\in A \text{ , }y\in B $, then choose two points $a\in A, b \in B. $

\begin{align}
d(x, y) &\le d(x, a) +d(a, b)+d(b, y)\\
&\le diam(A) +diam(B) +d(a, b) \end{align}

Hence, $d(x, y) - diam(A) - diam(B) $ is a lower bound of$ \{d(a,b):a\in A,b\in B \}$.

So, \begin{align}d(x, y)-diam(A) -diam(B) &\le Inf \{d(a,b):a\in 
A,b\in B \} \\ 
&\le d(A, B) 
\end{align}

Hence, $ diam(A) +diam(B) +d(A, B)$ is an upper bound of the set $\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\cup B\}$

And so,\begin{align}diam(A\cup B) &= sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\cup B\}\\
&\le diam(A) +diam(B) +d(A, B)\end{align}.

I want to know , is there any logical gaps?

Is my proof correct?

How many marks do you want to give me out of 5 ?

Please verify the proof. Thanks.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are not defined in Step $1$ - without quantification, this statement is certainly too general.

Comment: In Case 1, you conclude that $diam(A)+diam(B)+d(A,B)$ is an upper bound on $\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\cup B\}$.  There is no way you could conclude this since your original assumption on $x$ and $y$ in that case is that $x,y\in A$.

Comment: It seems that the statement $d(x,y)-diam(A)-diam(B)$ is a lower bound on $\{d(a,b):a\in A, b\in B\}$ is completely unused.  The next line goes back to the previous inequality.

Comment: All right, sir, I understand. Thanks. It will help me a lot.

Comment: In Case 1, there is a line $diam(A)\leq diam(A)+diam(B)+d(A,B)$.  This requires knowing that $0\leq diam(B)+d(A,B)$.  Do you know this is true from some lemma?  You may need to state that each of $diam(B)$ and $d(A,B)$ are nonnegative when $A$ and $B$ are nonempty (how are they defined if $A$ or $B$ is empty?)

Comment: Your original assumption on $A$ and $B$ is that they are bonded (bounded?) sets.  Does this imply that they are nonempty?

Comment: No sir. Diameter is only defined for a non empty set. That's way it is not mentioned initially.

Comment: Then, you must assume that $A$ and $B$ are not empty for your statements to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your proof.

It begins with “Step 1: $d(x, y) \in \{d(x,y):x,y\in A\cup B\}$”. This is meaningless. What are $x$ and $y$?

This is followed by “Case 1”. At least, there should be a Case 2 after that.

I would perhaps give $3$ marks in $5$, at most.

Comment: @S.G. It still has issues, you might want to wait before asking for a recheck

Comment: As @MichaelBurr wrote, it still has issues. For instance, now you have “Case 1: Both $x,y\in A$”. That's the Case 1 of *what*? Besides, I have provided an answer to your *original* question. Do you think that it is correct to change the question in such a way that my answer (or any potential answer) doesn't apply anymore?

Comment: It looks correct now.

Answer (score -1):

Overall, you should read through your proof and confirm that the following holds:

1. Every variable is (clearly) defined.  Every variable should be introduced before being used and we should be told in which set it lives.
2. Make sure that every line is needed.  There are some statements that are never used or lines that don't follow from the previous ones.  Look forward to identify where each line is used and identify exactly which lines lead to each subsequent line.  Make sure that each conclusion is possible from your assumptions (since you assume $x,y\in A$ for Case 1, you can't conclude anything about points that are not in $A$).
3. Make sure that the overall plan is made clear.  You have cases, but the explanation of how those cases fit together to give the proof is missing.

There are several instances of each of these issues in your proof and you should check for them yourself.